# Night \ Dark theme

Tags: cartocss

I'm using OSM by the
[switch2osm guide](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-16-04-2-lts/).
All works well, 
now im looking for a night mode or dark map design.
I tried to install the osm-bright (ee have a fork called osm-night)
OSM bright have a broken link how to install on Ubuntu. The link now redirecting to Mapbox website, and the web page\guide is no longer exists on the Mapbox website.

How can I accomplish this?